# How Can I Route A WAN IP Request To My Loopback Address And Port?

Tags: linux, route, loopback

I have two virtual machines on my laptop. One of virtual machines want to reach an IP address (I have the IP) and I want to route this request to another virtual machine's port. I changed the default gateway address of the first virtual machine. Now I need to add a route to route this request to my second virtual machine's loopback address's port. I'm trying this command for it:

```
route add -net [FIRST MACHINE'S DESTINATION IP] netmask 255.255.255.0 dev eth0
```

And finally, it's not working. How can I do it?
I searched it on internet and can't find the answer..

Answer (score 0):

I tried a alternative method for it and it worked.

I create a new NAT Network for these virtual machines. Configured DHCP for the virtual machines to take same IP block of the first virtual machine's destination IP. Then I listen the destination port from second virtual machine using "netcat". And finally, It worked.

So there is still a problem because I can't find any answer of the method which I want to use but this alternative method is working for it. You can use it.